# Slow video-capturing with opencv 2.3.1

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there a way to stream video with opencv faster?

i'm using

```
Mat img;
VideoCapture cap(.../video.avi);
for (;;) {
    cap >> img;
    ...
    here is some calculations
}
```

Thanks

Comment: That is C++, not C. Mat and VideoCapture are both from the C++ interface of OpenCV. I suggest you retag your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the frame grabbing procedure is pretty straightforward, the slowness you are experiencing could caused by *some calculations* consuming your CPU, decreasing the FPS displayed by your application.

It's hard to tell without looking at the code that does this.

But a simple test to pinpoint the origin of the problem would be to simply remove *some calculations* and make a simple application that read the frames from the video and displays them. Simple as that! If this test works perfectly, then you know that the performance is being affected by the calculations that are being done.

Good luck.

Comment: the _some calculations_ is using [this tutorial](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html) not with image, but with video as an _img_scene_

Comment: In that case, we know for sure that the performance is being seriously affected by *some calculations*. No need to investigate it further. If you want better performance with that code, invest $ to have a better computer with more processing power.

Comment: By the way, review your other questions and accept some answers.

Comment: so i guess if i'll load all frames in some array and then will make calculations, it will be the same result, right?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that those calculations are too heavy for your CPU.